# better way to do html updates then to expose javascript in rails3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a following code that is part of the _form.html.erb code. Basically I have a form in which I have a observe_field function where on change, it will set fields' values without refreshing the page. Following is my html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // When DOM loads, init the page.
    $(function() {
      // Executes a callback detecting changes with a frequency of 1 second
      $("#id_element_placeholder").observe_field(1, function( ) {                                       
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/students/get/" + this.value,
        success: function(data){
            $('#last_name').attr('value', data.student.last_name);
            $('#building').attr('value', data.student.building);
            $('#room').attr('value', data.student.room);                                                
        }
        });
      });
    });

  </script>
```

Problem here is that I'm exposing lot of my code in javascript. Is there a better way to do it without exposing code in javascript?

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
def get
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render :json => @student }
     end
end
```

Basically I get an id in a form and from there I have to get the corresponding object and update the fields on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your design requires you to make AJAX calls to query student info by id, then you need to expose a URL for the call.  If you don't want to expose a JSON data structure, you could return a chunk of HTML (instead of JSON), and replace the contents of the container of all of the controls you mention above.

Comment: How would that help anything? The only thing sending html over the wire will give you is a more sluggish interface.

Comment: He says he wants to avoid "exposing code in javascript".  Returning an HTML snippet will do so.  Otherwise he has to return some sort of data structure and parse it on the client side. Of course there's going to be trade-offs - in this case, a more rigid interface and a paltry increase in data over the wire.